# Hidden divs appear for a fraction of a second on page load

Tags: jquery, html, css

Ok, so I've been playing around with jQuery for just over a month now and understand a few basic concepts, but please reply in the context of a newbie!

My navigation bar utilizes jQuery to do the following:

- make drop down buttons interactive
- Hide and close a secondary navigation bar for, well.. quick navigation.

The problem: when a page opens, divs that should be hidden appear for a fraction of a second before jQuery hides them.

The jQuery is found in an external .js file, and is linked at the bottom of each PHP page, just above the closing body tag.

The jQuery goes a little like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(#example1).hide();
    $(#example2).hide();

    Interactive code here. etc etc
};
```

Any ideas on how to make the jQuery execute entirely, before the page is loaded?

Comment: Can you not hide the elements via CSS as part of the HTML, rather than setting them via client-side code?  That would remove the time-delay between the rendering and the document.ready

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use CSS to hide elements:

```
#example1, #example2 {
    display: none;
}
```

You might be able to hide these elements right away with JQuery by taking them out of the `ready function`.

```
$('#example1, #example2').hide();

$(document).ready(function () {
    ...
});
```

Comment: I suggest using class instead of individual selectors (which is more easily switched on and off as needed), unless there are really only going to be one or two on the entire site ever (edit: and they never need to be unhidden).

Comment: I agree, I only accommodated for the task at hand though.

Answer (score 2):

You can fix this by hiding the specific elements with CSS.

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS to hide the elements:

```
display: none;
```

The $(document).ready() listener means that the code will be started after the page is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You should hide elements with CSS not with `.hide`. Maybe by just doing

```
#example1,
#example2 {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All `$('#example2').hide()` does is sets CSS on the element to `display: none;`. The best way to prevent the elements from showing up for that split second is to have them hidden in your CSS styles.  You can just do

```
#example1,#example2 { display: none; }
```

in your CSS. The CSS is parsed and takes effect faster than JavaScript because it is designed to affect the way your document displays, whereas JavaScript's purpose is more aimed towards manipulating functionality of your HTML documents.

Answer (score 1):

As stated already, but I think here more thoroughly explained, I use CSS, but I use a CSS class instead of assigning it to individual elements/ids.

E.g., in my CSS file:

```
.ninja {
    display:none;
}
```

Then apply that class to the elements that should start as hidden.

Then in your js just add/remove the class on the fly as needed.

For example, in jQuery:

```
$('someselector').removeClass('ninja');
```

Answer (score 1):

Although there are several answers here, they are all hiding your elements through css (which you may not want if you want the elements to show if js is turned off)

For this I have a simple fix - after your `<body>` do a

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.write('<div class="js">');</script>
```

and then before your end body tag, close the div:

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.write('</div>');</script>
```

This way you can add styles to your css that will only affect js whilst the document is loading and not have to worry about if the dom has loaded them before trying to hide them, eg:

```
.js #example1 {display:none;}
```